# Troubles creating assembly in MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I had intentions to import the .NET assembly with SQL functions to MS SQL Server.

I've been trying to import it like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A9000030...
```

It was generated by my SQL project in Visual Studio

After that I needed to also create the referenced assemblies, like 'Microsoft.CSharp'

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.CSharp]
FROM 'path to dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

And then I've got the error like this:

> Assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp' references assembly 'system.dynamic, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.'

And now I really don't understand. As far as I know, System.Dynamic is not an assembly, but a namespace in System.Core.dll. And the System.Core is supported by MS SQL Server and imported by default. Is there any way to resolve such issue and successfully import such assembly?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this but I think things like Microsoft.CSharp are in the GAC and don't need to be registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (System.Dynamic.dll) really is an assembly - you can find it in the GAC and on disk; it has lots of the implementation details that C# uses to implement `dynamic`. You don't normally see it because all the types are `internal`, but it uses:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.CSharp, PublicKey =002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007d1fa57c4aed9f0a32e84aa0faefd0de9e8fd6aec8f87fb03766c834c99921eb23be79ad9d5dcc1dd9ad236132102900b723cf980957fc4e177108fc607774f29e8320e92ea05ece4e821c0a5efe8f1645c4c0c93c1ab99285d622caa652c1dfad63d745d6f2de5f17e5eaf0fc4963d261c8a12436518206dc093344d5ad293")]
```

so those implementation details are available to Micrsoft.CSharp.dll

The database is 100% correct here.

Comment: Thank you, I've really found this assembly in GAC, imported it and everything worked like charm